# Confused with output while working with Strings

Tags: java

```
    String sb1 = new String("Soft");
    String sb2 = new String("Soft");

    System.out.println("ANS1->" +sb1 == sb2);
    System.out.println(sb1 == sb2 + " After result");
    System.out.println("ANS2->" +sb1.equals(sb2));
```

This leads to output as below, but i dont understand why "ANS1" and "After result" texts are not displayed. Kindly help on this.

false

ANS2->true

Comment: @Biffen - Nope. It isn't

Comment: try to use `equals` instead of `==` as u used in your third output

Answer (score 5):

Because : `"ANS1->" +sb1 == sb2` ==> `("ANS1->" +sb1) == sb2`.
Now, the compiler does this and prints `false` because `("ANS1->" +sb1) !=sb2`.

Even : `System.out.println("ANS1->" +sb1 == sb1);` prints `false` :P

Comment: Thanks lot.. :)

Correct way to code is "System.out.println("ANS1->" +(sb1== sb2));"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to TheLostMinds´ answer:

```
System.out.println("ANS1->" + (sb1 == sb2));
System.out.println((sb1 == sb2) + " After result");
```

Now you see the "lost" strings.